# How do I run a web app code LOCALLY?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, server

I've written a RESTful web api for my client (android app) to use.
I need to implement another application, a local desktop application, which accesses `Databases` classes which are already implemented for the server side.

I don't know how to.

Specifically, this class for a server side:

```
public Database(String TableName, String KeyName) throws SQLException, NamingException {
  mTableName = TableName;
  mKeyName = KeyName;

  InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/nasdaq_companies");
}
```

Right now there is an exception thrown (NoInitialContextException) which makes perfect sense because I am missing context.xml or specifically within it this resource is missing

```
<Resource name="jdbc/nasdaq_companies" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nasdaq_companies"
          username="*****" password="*****" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

Assuming that the server == localhost, How do I add a context resource to a local java application? (Or otherwise, how do i fix this problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about running something like a console app I solved it by setting up context manually by calling method in Main that looked something like this:

```
    public static void setupInitialContext() {
            try {
                NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(new InitialContextFactoryBuilder() {

                    @Override
                    public InitialContextFactory createInitialContextFactory(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
                        return new InitialContextFactory() {

                            @Override
                            public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
                                return new InitialContext() {

                                    private Hashtable<String, DataSource> dataSources = new Hashtable<>();

                                    @Override
                                    public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {

                                        if (dataSources.isEmpty()) { //init datasources
                                            MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
                                            ds.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SomeDB");
                                            ds.setUser("dbuser");
                                            ds.setPassword("dbpass");
                                            dataSources.put("jdbc/SomeDataSourceName", ds); 
    //lets add another datasource (optional)
                                            MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
                                            ds.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OtherDB");
                                            ds.setUser("dbuser");
                                            ds.setPassword("dbpass");
                                            dataSources.put("jdbc/OtherDataSourceName", ds);    
//you can keep adding these as you need                                         
                                        }

                                        if (dataSources.containsKey(name)) {
                                            return dataSources.get(name);
                                        }

                                        return null; //or throw exception Java style :)
                                    }
                                };
                            }

                        };
                    }

                });
            }
            catch (NamingException ne) {

            }
        }
```

EDIT:

You use this method by calling it first in your Main and after that getting those datasources should work

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

        setupInitialContext();

        Context initContext = new InitialContext();        
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("jdbc/SomeDB");

}
```

PS: i think i found this way on StackOverflow as well but honestly can't remember where :(

Comment: That's EXACTLY what i meant,yes. However notice that 4 lines are duplicated in your code, and on top of that the method lookup should return an object is an error for the very last method, I'm assuming if nothing is found then return null, I am not sure though (might also through?). If you can fix this in your answer I will appreciate it, I will try it literally now thank you so much for helping out you probably saved me many many hours :)

Comment: Edited for return null or throw exception. As for duplicated lines they are just example that you can put multiple datasources if you wish (one will suffice) I edited that with comment as well.

Comment: OK there is a problem: On the class itself if I call initContext.lookup("jdbc/SomeDB") then it works locally but not on the server (it throws NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/nasdaq_companies] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].). If I use  ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/nasdaq_companies") then it works on the server but not locally :( I need this class to work both locally and on the server :P

Comment: can you try defining it as "java:comp/env/jdbc/nasdaq_companies" instead of just "jdbc/nasday_companies" ? so your line in setupInitialContext would look like: dataSources.put("java:comp/env/jdbc/nasday_companies", ds);

Comment: Thank you so much dude!! Also since you are online: I know close to nothing about this subject (Context in a server container would be my GUESS for the name of this subject), How do i learn more about it so that I won't make silly mistakes? (It is almost always a bad idea to code without realizing what you are doing :) ). Thanks again man! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)As for learning, I'm a not an expert myself on the subject unfortunately so I'm afraid I would only steer you in wrong direction with any advice :(